# Ownership of object - which widget should delete it?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qwidget, ownership

I have a set of widgets with a complex relationship. One of them MUST create an item, that I think must be stored as a pointer. The other, created later, receives the pointer to the item - a `QGraphicsScene` - and places it in a view.

The question: on close, who, if any, should delete the item ?

---

`Widget`: contains gui elements that enact changes on a `QGraphicsScene* m_scene` (a derived class) and its items.
`MainWidget`: contains a scrollArea where it places `Widget`, a scrollArea containing a `QGraphicsView`, and a toolbox. (it is designed to be reusable by different widgets)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget* w = new Widget();
    MainWidget m(w);
    m.show();
    return a.exec();
}

MainWindow:: MainWindow(Widget *contentWidget, QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui:: MainWindow), 
    m_contentWidget(contentWidget), 
    m_canvas(contentWidget->getCanvas())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->myView->setScene(m_canvas);
    ui->editArea->insertWidget(0, m_contentWidget);
}
```

Both classes have

```
MyCanvas *m_canvas;
```

---

So - on close - which widget should delete `m_canvas` ? The `Widget` class, who is the owner, or `MainWidget` class, which contains the view holding the scene ?

(deleting it in the `Widget` - the logical owner - makes program crash, my guess is because `MainWidget` still requires it as part of the ui)

Comment: If you are not maintaining an old code base, you should already be using smart pointers. They automagically solve ownership issues and who must care about the respective delete as a consequence.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out, how to use smart pointers for my scene item.

Answer (score 1):

The *owner* of the pointer is the is the one that should perform the delete. You've identified that `Widget` is the owner therefore it is the one that should delete the resource.

---

It seems reasonable that `Widget` is the owner since `m_canvas` is initialized using `contentWidget->getCanvas()` (where `contentWidget` is of type `Widget`) which leads me to assume `Widget` is also the one that called the `new` operator.

Comment: Yes that is true - but my guess is, MainWidget gets upset if the canvas is deleted while he still holds a reference in the view... Something is upset and crashing.

Comment: @Thalia I don't see how there would be a problem with the code you posted. `Widget` is never deleted which makes me believe the `MyCanvas` instance is never deleted. In any event, you are definitely required to make sure the `MyCanvas` instance lives for as long as others are using it. This is really a different question that would require more detail to know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: @Thalia Does performing `ui->myView->setScene(nullptr);` before the `MyInstance` instance is deleted resolve your problem?

Comment: Widget is placed in a layout inside MainWidget  - that makes it a child of MainWidget, so it will be deleted as part of the deletion of MainWidget. Oh - just saw new comment - I will try it. - Update - still crashes if I set scene to null.

Comment: Or `setScene(new QGraphicsScene());` - still crashes.

Comment: @Thalia I suggest you create a new question (possibly deleting this one) about the crash and show how you're trying to avoid the crash. I'd also provide details about the crash (e.g., do you get any error messages?)

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas class seems to inherit from `QGraphicsScene`, which inherits from `QObject`. As long as it has a parent, no deletion is necessary; the parent object handles this.

Whichever class is *not* the parent of the `MyCanvas` object should store the pointer with `QPointer` to guard against dangling pointers.